# How do I view & debug contentScriptFile sources in Firefox debugger?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

I'm making [an add-on](https://github.com/groovecoder/fx-doiuse/tree/e0e196e9be93258b8efcc18e54e07fdb3c0fafdf) with a simple content script using `tab.attach` and `contentScriptFile`:

`index.js`:

```
tab.attach({
  contentScriptFile: "./doiuse-script.js"
});
```

`data/doiuse-script.js`:

```
if (document.body) document.body.style.border = '5px solid red';
console.log("document.styleSheets: " + document.styleSheets);
```

I have `devtools.chrome.enabled = true` and `devtools.debugger.remote-enabled = true` so I can use the [Add-on Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger).

But, when I open the Add-on Debugger, I don't see my `doiuse-script.js` source?

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question while asking it.

As mentioned in [the Add-on Debugger docs about content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger#Content_scripts), the Add-on Debugger does not show content script sources unless/until they are loaded. So, the Add-on Debugger won't show the content script source until you reload the page on which the content script activates.